# How to convert numerical numbers to alphabet?

Tags: sql

```
1-A
2-B
3-C
Etc etc
```

Please help me writing the function.

Comment: Please try the problem first before asking for help.

Comment: `SELECT CHAR(88)`

Comment: What if number greater than `z` value i.e. `27 = ?`,`28 = ?`

Comment: I removed all those dbms tags. Feel free to put one of them back, the one for the dbms actually used here.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Answer (score 0):

Try This Logic

```
DECLARE @MyNum INT = 1
SELECT 
    CharVal = CHAR(64+@MyNum), 
    InputNum = @MyNum
```

And try this if you want to generate the complete List

```
DECLARE @Start INT = 1

;WITH CTE
AS
(
   SELECT 
      CharVal = CHAR(64+@Start), 
      SeqNo = @Start

   UNION ALL

   SELECT
      CharVal = CHAR(64+SeqNo+1),
      SeqNo = SeqNo+1
      FROM CTE
         WHERE CHAR(64+SeqNo+1) <> 'Z'

)
SELECT
   *
   FROM CTE
```

Set the Value from @Start with the position from where you wish to start

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @alpha VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @alpha = 'M'
select CASE WHEN CAST(CAST(@alpha as VARBINARY) AS INT) >= 64 THEN CAST(CAST(@alpha as VARBINARY) AS INT) - 64 END
```

Try out this, just converting Alphabet to ints. You can run it in loop and get your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres you can simply do:

```
select nr, chr(nr + 64)
from generate_series(1,26) as t(nr)
order by nr;
```